# css not loading on IE8

Tags: css, html

my website works fine on chrome but when i run on IE(mine is 8 the third party demands site to be working on IE 11 and chrome) the horizontal menu with the sub menu items becoming ordered lists.how to correct this

```
#menu {
width:960px;
position:relative;
margin: 0px auto;
background:#0093d0;
}
nav {
 position:relative;
}
nav ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
nav ul li {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
nav ul li a {
font:bold 12px Arial;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
padding:7px 10px;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
}
nav ul li:hover > a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
background:#ccc;
}
nav ul li a.current {
background:#fff;
color:#0093d0;
}
nav ul ul {
min-width:200px;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
z-index:666;
background:#0093d0;
display:none;
}
nav li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}

nav ul ul li {
display:block;
width:100%;
}
nav ul ul a {
padding:7px 10px;
display:block;
color:#fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
text-align:left;
}


<!DOCTYPE html><!--using html 5-->
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta name="description" content="for family safety">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-    scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />         
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
  <body>
 <div id="header"><!--starts of header-->
<div id="site_title">
<h2>'IMPROVING HSE AT HOME' site!</h2>
<img class="image_wrapper image_fr" src="images/Logo_lockup.jpg" alt="image" />
<br><br><br>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="menu"> <!--starts of menu-->
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="health.html" class="current">Health</a></li>

    <li><a href="safety.html">Safety</a></li>

    <li><a href="environment.html">Environment</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div><!--end of menu-->
<div id="main"><!--start of main-->
 <div class="inner_box last">
 <div class="col_w900_last">
     <div class="col_w420 lp_box float_l">
        <div class="inner_box">
            <h2>HEALTH</h2>
               <P class="intro">Due to weather conditions in our Region, d healthy places to live.<br>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col_w420 float_r">
        <div class="post_box">
        <div class="post_header">
          <img width="400" height="400" src="images/Health_93453718.jpg" alt="Image 001" />
           </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div> 
</div>  <!--end of main-->
<div id="footer">

</div> <!-- end of footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait...you're developing *for* IE11 in IE8?

Comment: Seriously now, I checked the snippet in IE11 and it looks quite similar to other browsers. So you should be OK.

Comment: Any reason you can't use IE11? There are free test editions available in virtual machines for the precise purpose of testing what websites look like in various versions.

Comment: That said, I'm not entirely sure WHY IE8 would ignore so many of the styles. I mean, it's not like IE8 doesn't know about `>` or `inline-block` and stuff. The multiple X-UA-COMPATIBLE lines worry me though; wouldn't the second one override the first one?

Comment: @paulie_D:they demand  it should also work for IE 11,but how make it compatible with all browers(IE 7,8,9)

Comment: @MrLister:happy to know it works fine on IE11.shall i write a seperate css for ie 7,8 ? one more thing am very much new to programming can u suggest me a good edition for the testing

Comment: can you plz show me your code or image which problem you face?

Comment: @PratikParekh:•Home
•Health 
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
•Safety 
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
•evt 
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water
◦Drinking water...output comes like this

Comment: @PratikParekh: i hv updated the css code here

Comment: @hena, IE8 doesn't recognize HTML5 tags (like nav). Fix: https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv

Comment: i removed nav and tried still no use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's an attempt to use CSS and HTML5 elements and properties which do not work in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must clear the floats in IE8. Try to add a div with style clear:both after your floating elements and test again.

BTW, why the hell would you use IE8? There are a whole lot of HTML5 and CSS3 not supported in IE8. IE9 is a little better, but IE10 is another world. If you are not ASKED to support IE8, by all means, just DON'T use IE8 to test the site.

Comment: @Rob Would like to hear more of that. :O

Comment: This is not the place for that but adding to the DOM non-semantic, empty elements to do what CSS can do on its own is improper at best.

Comment: I agree that it's not a good practice, but IE8 doesn't understand :after, so in the above case adding the empty div is probably the better among some bad solutions.

Comment: :after is only one method. There are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `list-style:none;` on `ul` tag not on `li` tag , Like this

```
nav ul{
list-style: none;
}
```

try this.

Comment: @Partik Parekh: i have added the html code here.it would be great if u can go through that and one more thing i am troubling with this page is in the header logo moving towards center when i press print screen.